# How do I delete an owner generated question in GMB using api v1?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I created a code in laravel about fetching the questions and answers posted on Google My business Page.

It works fine but, deleting my own question is not working.

Here's the problem. When I press the delete, it works fine, it is removed in the website I am working on. Also the question is not getting fetched at all but it is still on the business in Google and I had to delete it manually.

has anyone experienced this issue before?

https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/qanda/rest/v1/locations.questions/delete

I tried looking at the documentation but nothing seems to pop out. I tried contacting the support but they haven't replied yet.

I looked for other resources like videos and similar issue in other forums but alas, nothing seems to fir the issue I am working on.

Comment: Sharing your code here would help resolve the issue

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.